# About \ phalcon \ mvc \ Application.zep

Tags: php, phalcon

I need to update from PHP 7.3 to PHP 8.0 or PHP 8.1.

About composer.json php from ~ 7.3.0 to ^ 8.0, ext-phalcon from ^ 3.3.0 to 5.0.0 beta3 I think I have to update to

It changed as follows

**cphalcon-3.3.0\cphalcon-3.3.0\cphalcon-3.3.0\phalcon\mvc\Application.zep**

```
/**
 * Handles a request
 */
abstract public function handle();
```

**cphalcon-5.0.0beta3\cphalcon-5.0.0beta3\cphalcon-5.0.0beta3\phalcon\Mvc\Application.zep**

```
/**
 * Handles a MVC request
 */
public function handle(string! uri) -> <ResponseInterface> | bool
```

What should I specify for the uri?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
echo $application->handle($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])->getContent();
```